# Unable to establish connection from Objects to Properties in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, interface-builder

I am updating an old iOS app that I did not write.

I need to swap a UITextField for a UILabel. Simple, right?

I opened the XIB put my new UILabel in and went to drag the connector from the .h to the UILabel, and it would not connect.

Though the other objects in the view respond to their connection, I cannot hookup the Interface Builder object with its respective property.

[image: Other objects respond to their connection]

Even click and dragging doesn't cause a connection to be established.

[image: Drag and Drop doesn't work]

The custom class is listed.

[image: Custom Class Hookedup]

Has anyone else had the issue?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This happens only with me, when I try to drag to the wrog code file.
Make sure you choose automatic in the top left of the code file. Or you can write the property yourself. and then link it directly form the XIB file.

Comment: The correct code file is selected. That's what is so frustrating.

Comment: Have you tried to drag the ○ before line number 35 and drop to view in IB? And confirm code and storyboard are in the same target of project.

Comment: Yes, I have tried all of those things.

Comment: Have you tried to "ctrl" + "click" over the custom view (last screenshot but also pressing "ctrl") in the left navigation bar in order to check the available `IBOulets` for that view?